# Botão que chama outra tela e outro botão na tela nova que volta para a tela antiga

Tags: android

Como posso fazer um botão que chame outra tela, e na outra tela ter um botão que quando clicar, volta para a tela inicial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tela 1

```
final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this@Tela1, Tela2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

> Tela 2

Você pode utilizar um botão qualquer ou até mesmo definir um botão de navegação na sua `Toolbar`.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back" /> <!-- este é o icone de navegação -->
```

E na classe da Tela 2:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Você também pode utilizar um botão qualquer que o resultado será o mesmo. O que acontece acima é que você inicia uma nova **Activity**, mas a anterior continua no **Stack**, ou seja, ela não foi finalizada, apenas colocada em pausa. Então, ao dar **finish**, ela é reaberta, pois já que ela permaneceu na fila de **activities**.

Sinta-se livra para fazer novas perguntas no comentário desta resposta, caso houver alguma dúvida.

Comment: Estou com um problema no código da tela 1:  Intent i = new Intent(this, ProxPasso.class); Cannot resolve constructor

Comment: Você está utilizando o código acima dentro de um Fragment?

Comment: Estou usando dentro do onCreate

Comment: Okay, tente o seguinte: `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProxPasso.class);` e diga-me se resolve.

Comment: Para de funciona a aplicação

Comment: Certo. Você sabe onde fica o arquivo AndroidManifest.xml? E se sim, a Activity ProxPasso está definida neste arquivo?

Comment: Não, mas eu acabei de copiar a da Tela 1 e funcionou, porém estou com um erro na tela 2,  setSupportActionBar(toolbar); cannot be applied to (android.widget.toolbar)

Comment: É porque a referência está incorreta. Deve ser `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` ao invés de `Toolbar`

Comment: Procure algum `import` que leve à Toolbar e troque por android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar e seu problema será resolvido. E se no seu layout for Toolbar, troque para android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar como no código da resposta.